# Keyboard layout switch in different windows

Tags: keyboard, release-hera

How can I enable different keyboard layout for different applications (different windows)? 
I'm use elementary OS 5.1 Hera.

Каким образом можно настроить чтобы переключение раскладки клавиатуры действовало не на все открытые (открываемые после) приложения (окна)?

Спасибо!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020/01/24, this is not possible.

There is an open issue in the `elementary/gala` repository you can follow for improvements.

See [github.com/elementary/gala/issues/180](https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/180)